# Generating Sitemap.xml file for Dynamic sites in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, curl, sitemap

How can one crawl a site for all Unique links and Make/Write an XML file to the root of that Respective domain. I want something like when i call mydomain.com/generatesitemap.php And this file crawls all the links in the domain and writes them to file sitemap.xml. Is this possible in PHP with cURL?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your site. If it is simple site -- then the task is simple. Grab your site root page via curl or file_get_contents, preg_match all the links (see here, for the reference http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-extract-html-links-with-regular-expression/), then recursively grab all the links, which are inside your site, do not process links, which are allready processed.

The task become more complicated when JavaScript comes to play. If navigation uses JavaScript data, it will be difficult to obtain the links. There could be other navigation tricks, like select-combobox as dropdown menu.

The task could be even more complicated if you have pages with query strings. Say you have the catalogue section. And url are like this:

```
/catalogue
    /catalogue?section=books
    /catalogue?section=papers
    /catalogue?section=magazines
```

Is it one page or not?

And what about this one?

```
 /feedback
 /feedback?mode=sent
```

So you should take care of this cases.

There are many examples of such a crawlers in google search. Look at this for instance:

http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/